# Uninstall doesn't delete files within INSTALLDIR - Basic MSI - InstallShield 2012

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2012, basic-msi

I am creating a Basic MSI Installer using InstallShield 2012 Spring Professional.

Here I create a folder structure in application files as `C:\Program files\Test Setup\Productname`, `Test Setup` is the `INSTALLDIR`, and within this I have subdirectories one of which (`launch`) contains the `.exe` files.

I have added these files and the directory structure using the `Add files and folders` option in application files menu of Project Assistant.

After installing the product, when I uninstall it I find that while some `.exe` files are deleted, a few of the `.exe` files in the launch subdirectory wann't deleted. None of these `.exe` are started.

InstallShield is supposed to delete all the files and folders it created unless they have been modified or being used, but I am not running the files during the uninstalling nor have I changed any file. Where am I going wrong?