# Install file create by InstallShield 2012 sometimes did not get the proper INSTALLDIR when uninstall

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2012

I have one problem with InstallShield 2012.

I try to create an install file with InstallShield , this file runs fine in installation period , but when i use this file to do uninstall, it can't get the INSTALLDIR I chosen in UI during the install period.

And in additional, if i use the same InstallShield project to create install file, sometimes the output file can uninstall correctly, but sometime are not, i really feel confused.

I think the root cause is installer does not get the correct INSTALLDIR value,it get the default value but not the one input while installed.

Any idea about this issue?

Comment: Is this registry problem related:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/12838882/1150918
?

Comment: you mean the INSTALLDIR value stored in registry? how can I find it in regedit.

Comment: For some poople cleaning all registered components of their projects from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDlls` and reinstalling an application helped.

Comment: Your problem isn't clear; you say it's not getting `INSTALLDIR` as chosen previously, but not what impact that has. Does it fail to remove files, or is there a custom action that needs this information that then can't perform its task?

Comment: I need the INSTALLDIR value so I can do some custom action in the script

Answer (score 0):

To keep the InstallDir value, finally I got a workaround, we can add a component and set it's value as InstallDir, it solved my problem.